# How to stop TypeScript from resolving files with matching names when using moduleResolution NodeNext?

Tags: typescript

When `{"moduleResolution": "nodenext"}`, then import such as:

```
export { z } from 'zod'
```

gets transpiled to:

```
export { z } from './zod';
```

if there is a filename `zod.ts` in the same directory.

This is not intended. How do I disable this behaviour? i.e. the expectation is that `export { z } from 'zod'` remains as is.

Comment: If this is the expected behavior of nodenext, then you might have to settle for not having files with the same name as libraries, even though that's not ideal